If righteousness is once stated as a gift in Romans 5:17, is it sound to consider the appearance of the word as always a gift if not stated otherwise
My question relates to the treatment of the word “righteousness” in Romans 5:17, whereby it is called a “gift”, and whether one can always consider it as that, if it isn’t specified to be one’s own righteousness in view.
Romans 5:17 (KJV)

For if by one man's offence death reigned by one; much more they which receive abundance of grace and of the gift of righteousness shall reign in life by one, Jesus Christ.)

The reason why I am asking this, is related to the idea relayed in Romans 4:3 and the related passages describing the faith “counted” onto Abraham “for righteousness.”
Romans 4:3 (KJV)

For what saith the scripture? Abraham believed God, and it was counted unto him for righteousness.

If in fact this “righteousness” described was in fact also a “gift” as I am  in fact questioning, then the very faith, it would appear, described couldn’t be to Abraham’s credit to be responsible for producing the gift I would think.  Gifts are not of one’s own credit.  But rather the righteousness described was something given. So I wonder if what is being described is that the state all along of Abraham at this point was that he was already given faith as someone who had been justified, and therefore the righteousness itself is present - that it was “reckoned to him,” as simply an accounting of the fact that he had been given this gift already.

We can easily tie our thoughts into pretzels when worry too much technically. Consider it this way. God gifted Abraham faith, enabling him to believe, and through that faith as a conduit , a ledger of rights and wrongs was adjusted. Abrahams sins were credited to Messiah, Messiah’s obedience to the law, credited to Abraham. There is no pretzel to cause anxiety just peace and joy for those blessed to be revealed that Jesus is the Christ and which flesh and blood can never accept.

Questions about what the word 'righteousness' means in the Bible require us to distinguish between how it applies to humans, and how it applies to God. "There is none righteous, no, not one" the Bible says of sinful humans (Romans 3:10, quoting Micah 7:9). But God IS Righteous, and the only one who can gift faith that enables righteousness to be evaluated to humans. See John 17:25, Philippians 3:9 & Romans 5:15 as the question shows.
Then the question brings in Romans 4:3 and related passages describing the faith “counted” unto Abraham “for righteousness” asking if the word 'righteousness' always has to be stated as a gift given to people [the main question]. No, it does not, but what is vital is to get the correct meaning of Romans 4:3 – what was counted, credited or reckoned? The Received Text, The Textus Receptus (TR), renders Romans 4:3 as:

Episteusen de Abraam tw Thew ...kai elogisthe autw eis dikaiosunen
which reads "And Abraham believed God ...and there was evaluated to
him unto righteousness. [Note that elogisthe is an inflection of the verb logizomai"

Here is part of an explanation delving into this, but there is too much in the book I quote from to do the question justice. However, going to the link below enables the book to be brought up, read and used freely. Here is some explanation that should help with the related questions asked by the OP:

"There was evaluated is my own translation of elogisthe.  The Hebrew
of the original from which Paul quotes, which is Genesis 15:6, is
translated by the AV as '...and he counted it to him for
righteousness'. Young's Literal gives '...and He reckoneth it to him -
righteousness'. Green's Literal has '...and he it reckoned to him for
righteousness'.
However, I am informed that Hebrew does not always require a subject
to be stated and that, in this place, the idiomatic Hebrew can be
accepted as 'it was counted to him for righteousness'.
This idiomatic structure has been adopted by both the AV and Young's
Literal Translation in Psalm 106:31 where the Psalmist writes: 'and
that was counted unto him [Phinehas] for righteousness unto all
generations for evermore' (AV). 'And it was reckoned to him to
righteousness. To all generations - unto the age' (YLT)...
The evaluation of what is within the believing Abraham is expressed in
Genesis in Hebrew and is then further expressed in Greek in the
Septuagint (LXX). Paul quotes this place three times in Romans 4:3,
Romans 4:22 and Galatians 3:6, then James quotes it in James 2:23...
The Septuagint rendering, Paul's quotations and James's quotation of
the five words of the second half of the text appear, to me, to be
more correctly rendering, in Greek, the original Hebrew of the
passage, than the available English translations of the Hebrew which
Moses wrote, as preserved in the Masoretic text. The Greek is offering
a middle passive verb.
The verb elogisthe has no subject other than that implied by its
inflection. Bagster's Analytical Lexicon says that his word is the
third person singular, aorist 1, indicative passive.  To say 'it' was
accounted, or reckoned, is inappropriate as there is not 'it' in the
passage. There is Abraham and there is God and there is Abraham's
faith. To say 'it' was accounted, or reckoned, is stating that the
faith, itself, was accounted or reckoned unto righteousness.  This
implies that faith is being viewed as if it were righteousness. Which
it is not. It is a different thing. I do not believe that this is
what the words mean. Something, yes, is being accounted or reckoned or
evaluated. That something is within Abraham. But faith is not
righteousness, as such. Nor is faith a substitute for righteousness,
as such.
Further, the verb logizomai, of which elogisthe is an inflection,
is one of a type of verbs classed as deponent verbs over which there
is some controversy. My own understanding of the matter is that they
exhibit passive inflections but are not entirely passive in their
usage. They may be reflexive in nature, that is to say they may
involve activity directed at the self, and this can be called a
'middle' voice. I can be active. I can be passive, or I can respond to
the activity of another. The activity is not my own initiative,
actively. I respond to the initiative of another. It is not active,
but rather reactive.
Abraham believed God. And there was a response. The verb elogisthe
does not say who responded. It just states the fact of a response. The
response was to him (autw is the dative) and the response was unto
(it is eis) righteousness. I prefer not to use 'it'. I prefer to
leave 'it' unspoken and to say 'there was'.
One could leave the place blank and say: Abraham believed God ---and
was evaluated to him unto righteousness." Jehovah Tsidkenu, Nigel
Johnstone, pages 86 - 90, emphases mine. http://www.belmontpublications.co.uk

This is a deep subject and this answer only begins to open up the complexities. But as Greek was one of the tags, and Romans the other, this answer has delved into that. I hope it helps.

In Romans 3:10, Paul quotes from Psalm 14:1 and Psalm 53:3, that "There is no one righteous, not even one". He further elaborates in Romans 3:20, that "no one will be declared righteous in God’s sight by the works of the law; rather, through the law we become conscious of our sin."
Indeed, righteousness is a gift from God, representing the "pardon of sin" granted by His sovereignty. It is not something we can achieve on our own. In Romans 3:26, Paul highlights that Jesus demonstrated His righteousness to justify those who have faith in Him; "he (Jesus) did it to demonstrate his righteousness at the present time, so as to be just and the one who justifies those who have faith in Jesus."
Romans 5:17 reinforces this concept, connecting it back to the earlier passages in Romans 3. Similarly, Romans 4:3 draws a parallel between Abraham's faith and our belief in Jesus - "Abraham believed God, and it was credited to him as righteousness", is parallel to "We believe Jesus, and it was credited to us as righteousness".
However, it is essential not take this faith lightly. As Jesus warns in Matthew 7:21, mere claims of belief are insufficient. Only those who genuinely believe and receive the gift of righteousness will enter the kingdom of heaven.

“Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, but only the one who does the will of my Father who is in heaven.


OP's thought,

"So I wonder if what is being described
is that the state all along of Abraham
at this point
was that he was already given faith."


Scripture says that faith comes by hearing, and hearing by the word of.


189 akoḗ – properly, hearing; used of inner (spiritual) hearing that goes with receiving faith from God (Ro 10:17),


◄ 4487. rhéma ►word


Usage: a thing spoken
HELPS Word-studies
4487 rhḗma (from 4483 /rhéō, "to speak") – a spoken word, made "by the living voice" ("spoken-word") for the Lord speaking His dynamic, living word in a believer to inbirth faith
Ro 10:17: "So faith proceeds from (spiritual) hearing; moreover this hearing (is consummated) through a rhēma-word (4487 /rhḗma)

God sent His word into Abraham's ears along with directing his sight to look up at the heavens that are declaring the glory of God.  God opened up his ears to hear and his sight to see.
It was God who orchestrated the life of Abraham.  Even Sarah, who was unable to have children was put there by God.
He had a plan for Abraham to make him the father of not only Israel, but also of  many nations.
When he took him outside to look up at the stars, God gives Abraham a word about his future, and about his descendants, they would be as numerous as the stars.

The heavens declare the glory of God and the firmament shows His  handiwork. Psalm 19:1

Abraham got a glimpse of God's glory, he realized that it was God who made all those stars and here is the same one telling him he's going to have as many descendants as the stars there are up in heaven.
He is quite capable of then creating descendants since He is the creator of everything.
So Abraham was given a word by God and also sight  to help him see how many descendants he is going to have… Too many to count.
This was  God creating  faith in Abraham.  A total gift of God just like God who is always at work in a believer to will and to do His good pleasure.
Abraham believe God, despite his age and the age of his wife, and the fact that he had no son. This was an unconditional promise to Abraham and required nothing on Abraham's part. He believed God. This is the first example of faith- righteousness's.
He is declaring to Abraham the end from the beginning and He is doing it through Abraham, after all He is the potter and Abraham the clay.

I am God, and there is none like Me.
I declare the end from the beginning,
and ancient times from what is still to come.
I say, ‘My purpose will stand,
and all My good pleasure I will accomplish.’ Genesis 17:1

Just as Abraham was chosen by God to create a nation through, God has also chosen some this at  time to believe what He has done for all men through Christ's faith, His death, burial and His  resurrection.  He has chosen to give faith to believe in what He accomplished through the cross.

For if, by the offense of the one, death reigns through the one, much rather, those obtaining the super abundance of grace and the gratuity of righteousness shall be reigning  in life through the One, Jesus Christ.  Roman's 5:17


Adam enthroned  death, but Christ gives  believers, not only a full vindication from all guilt, but life and the right to reign with Him.
Concordant commentary.

God is the one who grants repentance.

Then to the Gentiles also God has granted repentance that leads to life” (Acts 11:18).


And the nations hearing were glad, and were glorifying the word of the Lord, and did believe -- as many as were appointed to life age-during; Acts 13:48

It is God who is in charge of making a believer at this point in time as Acts 16:14 shows.
God   not only gives the faith to believe God's word but opens the heart.

The Lord opened her heart, so that she gave attention to what Paul was saying.  Acts 16:14

Belief has been granted to some at this time to believe in Him

Because it has been granted to you on behalf of Christ, not only to believe in him. Philippians 1:29

Just as God chose Abraham for a  specific purpose and gave him faith, so God has also called people out at this time to be part of an administration in the coming eons as well.  See Ephesians 1:1-13

Jesus is the author and finisher of our faith.


For it is by grace you have been saved through faith, and this not from yourselves; it is the gift of God, not by works, so that no one can boast. For we are God’s workmanship.

So in summary, Believe is a gift of God that is totally of His doing from start to finish… Just like Jesus is the author and finisher of our faith.  He does it all and there are some who have a special salvation now.

for for this we both labour and are reproached, because we hope on the living God, who is Saviour of all men -- especially of those believing. 1 Timothy 4:10


Just as it is for us today, while living in the Ephesians 3:2 age of God's grace, it was by Abraham having faith that in God's eyes imputed righteousness was worthy of being gifted to Abraham.  Abraham simply believed God and that was sufficient.
There is no reason to believe that members of the church, the body of Christ, would have an eternal gift of God taken away.
Ephesians 4:30

And grieve not the holy Spirit of God, whereby ye are sealed unto the day of redemption.

Ephesians 2:8-9

For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God:
9 Not of works, lest any man should boast.

If it is by God's grace that we are gifted salvation, and not by anything of our own doing, why would God take back His gift?  That would imply that His gift (or retaining of it) was actually based on our meriting it, rather than simply offered to us because of His grace (love).  Therefore, we are gifted salvation (and the imputed righteousness that comes with it) upon having faith alone in Him alone once and for all of eternity.
Ephesians 1:12-13

That we should be to the praise of his glory, who first trusted in Christ.
13 In whom ye also trusted, after that ye heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation: in whom also after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy Spirit of promise,


Thank you for your reply Mark. I guess what I was getting at is the idea that the faith itself Abraham displayed was a gift, along with the according righteousness. Such that the faith cited in the Ephesians 2:8 verse you mention would also in fact be not of ourselves - although I have read that grammatically all three elements of that verse : faith, saved, and grace do not on their own grammatically agree as the “gift” talked of, but only in total as a complete phrase does it grammatically agree.  I was surprised that, Ephesians 1:11 leaves out “predestinated” in the ESV, when it is there.

I’m sorry, that was a mistake, “predestined” is included in Ephesians 1:11.  I am suggesting that predestination talks to the idea that Abraham’s faith would have to be predestined and therefore could not be something he chose, and therefore he can not get credit for that faith, and the righteousness that appears to result from it - which would be both also in themselves gifts.

@Matt Faith itself, as a gift, would then be based on God's foreknowledge of any predestined individual.  Both predestination and free will remain in tact when viewed in this light.   1 Peter 1:2
"Elect according to the foreknowledge of God the Father, through sanctification of the Spirit, unto obedience and sprinkling of the blood of Jesus Christ: Grace unto you, and peace, be multiplied."

Interesting. I tend to believe free will is then exempted by this view, because there is no other choice in this matter but the one you are destined to make, but thank you for your reply.

@Matt Everyone has the ability to believe (have faith), but God knows who actually will.  1 Tim 2:3-4 "For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour;
4 Who will have all men to be saved, and to come unto the knowledge of the truth."  Paul says that God wants "all" to be saved by coming to the knowledge of the truth.  What then is it that prevents that from happening?  The individual refuses to believe by their own free will.  They are then not granted faith based on their refusal to simply believe.  It is by God's foreknowledge of all of time that makes this possible.

Thank you Mark for the back and forth. It seems - correct me if I’m wrong - that your focus of the idea of predestination is regarding foreknowledge - I’ve seen that view before. Whereby, I read predestination as the true state you will be in, known ahead of time. Not limited to just knowledge. If you think about belief, I don’t think you can make yourself not believe something that you do believe, nor make yourself not believe something that you in fact believe to be true. You can lie out loud about what your true feelings of a matter are, but you can not make yourself not believe what you do

Yes, predestination is based on God's foreknowledge of us.  He knew before the creation of the world who would eventually believe.  Based on this foreknowledge of our belief, He then predetermined those believers to be His elect in Christ.  The belief of the believers was not 'forced' upon them.  They believed on their own accord.  Therefore both predestination and free remain intact.

Hi Mark, I don’t think - in fact I say confidently that I know - that it is not based on only his foreknowledge of in particular. God saved whom we decided he would save, and even was so generous as to give us a metaphor for it in Romans 9 in the metaphor of the potter.
Romans 9:15 (KJV) For he saith to Moses, I will have mercy on whom I will have mercy, and I will have compassion on whom I will have compassion.

Furthermore, God states that this is done (predestination) before anyone has done good or bad, right or wrong, using Jacob and Esau as a pictorial.
Romans 9:11 (KJV) (For [the children] being not yet born, neither having done any good or evil, that the purpose of God according to election might stand, not of works, but of him that calleth;).
So it has nothing to do with with our actions - good or bad - according to my reading. And God appears  to be emphasizing that. If it had to do with our actions, it would no longer be Grace.  Amen.

Summarizing my understanding of the main question:
Is "righteousness" always a gift unless stated otherwise?
Romans 5:17 is referred to as an example where "righteousness" is specified as a gift.

For if, because of one man's trespass, death reigned through that one man, much more will those who receive the abundance of grace and the free gift of righteousness reign in life through the one man Jesus Christ.

The Blue Letter Bible indicates that the word used in Romans 5:17 is - δικαιοσύνη dikaiosýnē, dik-ah-yos-oo'-nay
It also offers an outline of useage.

I. in a broad sense: state of him who is as he ought to be, righteousness, the condition acceptable to God

the doctrine concerning the way in which man may attain a state approved of God

integrity, virtue, purity of life, rightness, correctness of thinking feeling, and acting


II. in a narrower sense, justice or the virtue which gives each his due

What we see is that there is a broad range of possible meaning.
In the linked article there is a list of verses where the word is used. Reading through the list it becomes clear that dikaiosýnē is best understood in context.
Even in the given verse - Romans 5:17 - the context indicates that in this case a very specific kind of righteousness is indicated.
Romans 15

15 But the free gift is not like the trespass. For if many died through one man's trespass, much more have the grace of God and the free gift by the grace of that one man Jesus Christ abounded for many. 16 And the free gift is not like the result of that one man's sin. For the judgment following one trespass brought condemnation, but the free gift following many trespasses brought justification. 17 For if, because of one man's trespass, death reigned through that one man, much more will those who receive the abundance of grace and the free gift of righteousness reign in life through the one man Jesus Christ.

The righteousness Paul is describing is where the follower of Jesus is made acceptable to God because of the gift of Jesus. We cannot assume that everywhere the word "righteous" is used is a gift if not specified as being one's own righteousness.
There is another question concerning faith and whether the faith of Abraham or the faith of a follower of Jesus is also a gift.
Hebrews 11 has a lot to say about faith.

1 Now faith is the assurance of things hoped for, the conviction of things not seen. 2 For by it the people of old received their commendation. 3 By faith we understand that the universe was created by the word of God, so that what is seen was not made out of things that are visible.

Later Abraham's faith is used as an example.

8 By faith Abraham obeyed when he was called to go out to a place that he was to receive as an inheritance. And he went out, not knowing where he was going. 9 By faith he went to live in the land of promise, as in a foreign land, living in tents with Isaac and Jacob, heirs with him of the same promise.

Faith or believing is different than works (see the Romans 15 passage). I think another word for faith is "trust". The follower of Jesus surrenders their will - trusts - in Jesus death and resurrection to be made right before God, justified. Faith is not a work that earns a follower of Jesus justification. Faith is a response to the glory of God.
The gift is grace.
Faith, trust, believing makes receiving the gift possible.
Faith drives obedience (Hebrews 11:8)

But isn’t faith inevitably present if God decides to gift the righteousness described in Romans 15? Or do you believe that a person has faith on their own, God recognizes it, and then justifies that person/makes them righteous (same word)?

@Matt The gift is available to all - John 3:16 "God so loved the world that he gave his only son...." Acts 16:30-31 "...what must I do to be saved? ... Believe in the Lord Jesus and you will be saved...". Biblical belief is not mental acceptance. The Bible uses faith, trust and belief in similar ways. We accept the gift when we believe/trust/have faith. I recognize that this view is controversial. It's where I'm at in my Bible study. Check the greek words listed for "believe" in Blue Letter Bible as evidence https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=believe&t=KJV#s=s_lexiconc

God gives us many good gifts, among them faith and the resulting righteousness.  But a gift must be received. So the exchange requires both parties participation to be effectual.
A man with no job is starving, his neighbor leaves some groceries on the porch.  But in his pride he says that he won't accept charity, and so starves to death. It is not enough to have a savior if you refuse his offer.
(And there are those who blame the neighbor when the man starves, but that is best left for a different question!)
